# How to reinstall services?

Tags: mysql, directory, delete

I made a mistake and deletes the `etc/mysql/` directory. I installed lamp-server again (`sudo tasksel install lamp-server`) but I still don't have the `etc/mysql` directory and some of other mysql directories too I think. I want reinstall all the directories of Mysql but don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [HowToMySql](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/mysql.html) hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

If that doesn't help:

```
apt-get purge mysql-server && apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: İ think i delete OS mysql files. i can't install or uninstall.When i try it, get an error about mysql config files.i will format my computer and i will daily upload my system files to ubuntu one until i learn linux. Thanks for help :)